# How to test an API with multiple GET parameters with supertest?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai, supertest

I have an API like below (GET request)

```
/vehicle/{:vehicleId}/model/{:modelNumber}
```

which transforms like below in the use case

```
/vehicle/1000/model/1233
```

This would yield a specific JSON response.

How can I test the above GET API having multiple parameters with supertest?

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be the best way, but it is a valid answer.

```
var endpoint = '/vehicle/{:vehicleId}/model/{:modelNumber}';

function testGet(vehID, modelNo, done) {
    it('Test GET on vehicle ID = ' + vehID +
       ' and model number = ' + modelNo, function(done) {

        // url is defined elsewhere or passed in as desired
        var app = url + endpoint
            .replace('{:vehicleId}', vehID)
            .replace('{:modelNumber}', modelNo);

        request(app)
            .get()
            // any other .set or .expect commands
            .end(done);
    });
})
```

You can also use ES6 interpolation (backtick strings) like `` `/vehicle/${vehicleId}/model/${modelNumber}` ``

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `jest` for testing.

```
import { describe, test } from "@jest/globals";

function getEndpoint(vehicleId, modelNumber){
    return `/vehicle/${vehicleId}/model/${modelNumber}`;
}

describe("Test Configuration routes", (vehID, modelNo, done ) => {
    test(`Test GET on vehicle ID = ${vehID} and model number = ${modelNo}`,
        (done) => {
            // url is defined elsewhere or passed in as desired
            const app = url + getEndpoint(vehID, modelNo);

            request(app)
                .get()
                // any set statement
                // any expect statement
                .end(done);
        })
});
```